# How to identify best Model for univariate time series data?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, arima, arma

I have a time series data-

53.97   63.32   57.06   60.27   69.46   75.08   78.31   73.28   85.84   69.34   62.57   60.11   55.63   47.29   61.22   58.46   66.26   59.71   51.12   39.36   51.89   53.85   47.64   31.75   35.01   31.34   26.64   29.48.........

Are there any set steps to approach any time series or should I just look at statistical property of data that choose from available econometrics model like ARCH, AR, MA, ARIMA ?

Comment: Interesting side-issue of what is econometric. ARIMA for example may be useful in econometrics, but it was popularised by mainstream statisticians.

Answer (score 1):

Arpit,

Sometimes you need to consider Determinstic variables before you consider ARIMA variables.

I ran this model using two time trends (ie 0,0,0,1,2,3,4,etc) using Autobox(I am a developer) an AR1 and found one outlier at period 9.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, basically, you're recommending OP to use autobox, right? Otherwise, I don't see how is this an answer to OP's question

Comment: The outlier at 9 is an outlier presumably in the sense that it is awkward to fit to this kind of model, e.g. associated with large absolute residual. Otherwise it looks like an inlier to me!

Comment: Aksakal...you are right..I added some more words...

Comment: Nick - More of an "out" as "in" is near the trend line.

Comment: "This is not written in any text book". Hard to verify! But what precisely does "deterministic variable" mean here? If it means that a model is a mix of deterministic and stochastic elements, then that idea is standard in many places!

Comment: Thanks; I see now. The outlier corresponds to a small residual because it was accounted for _ad hoc_ by a pulse term.

Comment: Please do remember to disclose your affiliation with this product as per http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/promotion.

Comment: Scortchi - done....thx  Nick - I agree....removed. I think that the difference that is of importance here might better be stated as "multiple trend variables" are identified as the slope has changed over time.